# MediaElement binding mp3 file in MVVM wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, mediaelement

i'm makeing a small app where I have a list of buttons and each button plays an .mp3 file. As i have a big collection of files, i wanted to use MVVM.

My code is really easy:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel >                             
                            <Button Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" Click="Play" x:Name="Button1">
                                <MediaElement x:Name="Player" Source="{Binding mp3}" AutoPlay="False" />
                                <Button.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding image}"/>
                                </Button.Background>
                            </Button>
                            <StackPanel Width="311">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

And the xaml.cs i really dont know how to do it

```
private void Play(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player.Play();
    }
```

It sais "The name 'Player' does not exist in the current context" even if I get it out of the button

I know it must be a really simple question, but i'm just starting to learn how to program, so thanks for tour time

PS: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find the right "Player" since you'll have multiple ones. You can find the `CurrentItem` of the `ListBox` and then use the `name` of the control to find the `Player` before calling `.Play()`.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has sample code. Hope it helps.

Btw, another way would be to use one single media player (i.e. one instance outside the listbox) and set it's source with the url/address of each record before calling play(). That might make it easier for you to manage in case the user can only play one file at a time. IIRC, that might be a rule of WP apps as well.